# rxjs v6 / redux-observable v1.0.0: Operators not working in epic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-observable, rxjs6

I am using the latest version of redux-observable and Rxjs i.e

```
// My version
"redux-observable": "^1.0.0",
"rxjs": "^6.3.2"
```

The store - middleware, setup looks like this:

```
// Setting up middlewares
import { pingEpic } from './epics';
import pingReducer from './reducers/pingReducer';

import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { combineEpics, createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';

const rootReducer = combineReducers(pingReducer);
const rootEpic = combineEpics(pingEpic);

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware)
);

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
export default store;
```

And my epic looks like this

```
// pingEpic.js
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operator/mapTo';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
export const pingEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType('PING'),
    mapTo({ type: 'PONG' })
);
```

So when I executed the program for the first time I got the following error:

[image]

I googled it and [found a solution here](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-progressbar/issues/112#issuecomment-388332618) which says to install `rxjs-compat@6` (however it doesn't makes any sense) I installed that too! And then I ran into the following error:

[image].

I don't know what/where am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe Your store is somehow configured incorrectly. See how it's done here https://github.com/benawad/pingpong/blob/master/src/store.js

Comment: @Michal Cholewiński, this project uses the older versions. My store is same store you have pointed out but with the latest changes from 'redux-observable'. "Maybe Your store is somehow configured incorrectly" - Yes of course! My question is how to fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

instead of

```
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operator/mapTo';
```

source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#usage

Comment: with this it will look for `operator.js` file!

Comment: @SiddharthaChowdhury Added the source + fixed a type in the import.